# How to refresh tag without reloading page in google app script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I´m done in updating the cell and now I want to refresh automatically the tag after i click the button looped by on the table using `google-app-script`. Cannot understand the coding in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values). Please help me to solve this. Thanks!

**html**

```
<div  id="tables">
      <? var data = getData();?>
      <table id="tableShift1">
      <caption style="">Shift1</caption>
          <th>   ID   </th>
          <th>   Ldap   </th>
          <th>   Action   </th>
        <? for (var dataList = 1; dataList < data.length; dataList++) {
             if (data[dataList][2] == '') {?>
          <tr >
            <td><?= data[dataList][0] ?></td>
            <td><?= data[dataList][1] ?></td>
            <td><button onclick='google.script.run.setApproved("<?=data[dataList][0]?> ","<?=data[dataList][1]?>")' id='btnApprove'>Approve</button></td>
          </tr>
        <? }  
          } ?>
        </table>


        <table id="tableShift2">
      <caption>Shift2</caption>
          <th>   ID   </th>
          <th>   Ldap   </th>
          <th>   Action   </th>
        </table>
    </div>

<script
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
// The code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
$(function() {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData)
      .getData();
});

function showData(things2) {
  var table = $('#tableShift2');
  var kwit = ',';
  for (var i = 1; i < things2.length; i++) {
    table.append('<tr ><td>' + things2[i][0] + 
    '</td><td style=>' + things2[i][1]+ things2[i][0] + 
    '</td><td ><button onclick="google.script.run.setApproved("'+ things2[i][0] +'","'+ things2[i][1] +'")" id="btnApprove">Approve</button></td></tr>');
  }
}
</script>
  </body>
```

Comment: It is unclear as to what you are asking?

Comment: Im asking on how i can make my code to refresh the tag without reloading the page.

Comment: var elem=document.getElementById(id);element.innerHTML= new html;

Comment: What is the parameter `things2` receiving?  And what is it's data type?  `console.log('things2: ' + things2)`  You can open the browser's developer tools by hitting the f12 key and click the "console" tab.  Also, you can get the data type of a variable with `typeof variableName`:   `console.log('typeof things2: ' + typeof things2)`  If the data type of `things2` is a string, then you'll need to convert it to an array if you want to use it in your `for` loop.

Comment: what do you mean @Cooper?

Comment: You’re asking how to update an element of the DOM and a very common answer to that is to sssign that element an ID and then use document.getElementById  and then set the innerHTML equal to whatever you want. In app script you can use google.script.run to communicate with the script on the server

Comment: i dont get it. i cant catch what you saying, or dont know how to apply the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this:

Add and new function that provides the ability to return new data to refreshData()

```
function showData(things2) {
  var table = $('#tableShift2');
  var kwit = ',';
  for (var i = 1; i < things2.length; i++) {
    table.append('<tr ><td>' + things2[i][0] + 
                 '</td><td style=>' + things2[i][1]+ things2[i][0] + 
                 '</td><td ><button onclick="ApproveAndRefresh("'+ things2[i][0] +'","'+ things2[i][1] +'");" id="btnApprove">Approve</button></td></tr>');
  }
}


function ApproveAndRefresh(data1,data2){//you may need to include i
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(refreshData)
  .setApproved1(data1,data2);//a modified setApproved on the server that returns the appropriate html to the tableShift2 element
}

function refreshData(hl){
  document.getElementById('tableShift2').innerHTML=hl;
}
```

Comment: its not working @Cooper. Im thinking what is ¨hl¨ inside of the function refreshData(hl)... what will happen in this function?

Comment: hl is the html that refreshes tableShift2. You have to write the server function to create that html.

Comment: how about in this part `'</td><td ><button onclick="ApproveAndRefresh("'+ things2[i][0] +'","'+ things2[i][1] +'");" id="btnApprove">Approve</button></td></tr>');` is not working. I dont know how to fix it.